# Android Toolbar missing when applied BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, bottomnavigationview

I using BottomNavigationView and I have a issue when compile it with Toolbar. When I run app in the first time, the toolbar also missing a part look like a picture. Someone give me advice to fix it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Youre missing a property like `fitSystemWindows`

Comment: If you dont have a good hold on Constraint layout, use a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout, it ll work fine

Comment: @LamNguyen  I think to put the navigation bottom bar  view into content_main file